# Datagrid pagination, serverside easyui doesn't work

Tags: php, mysqli, datagrid, pagination, jquery-easyui

I am working with datagrid EasyUI, and I want to do a pagination.
In Datagrid displays only 10 row, a shows me 'Displaying 1 to 10 of 10 items'.

I don't know if the output array it's ok, to send to Datagrid.

Here is my code:

```
 public function get_temperatura_humedad_list($page, $rows) {
    $offset = ($page - 1) * $rows;
    $result = array();
    $rs = $this->db->consulta("select count(*) from dht22");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($rs);

    $result['total'] = $row[0];

    $rs = $this->db->consulta("select * from dht22 limit $offset, $rows");

    $items = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($rs)) {
        array_push($items, $row);
    }
    // $result["rows"] = $items;
    return $result['rows'] = $items;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your variable $rows to get the right offset. Something like this :

```
$rows = isset($_POST['rows']) ? intval($_POST['rows']) : 10;
$offset = ($page-1)*$rows;
```